# Google Sheet with vlookup /hlookup

Tags: google-sheets

How do I use the information in TABLE to find the number I want?

[image]

Comment: Thank eyllanesc's help.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
=VLOOKUP(F9, A10:D, MATCH(G9, A9:D9, ), )
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F9:F, A10:D, MATCH(G9:G, A9:D9, ), )))
```

Comment: Can ARRAYFORMULA be added to this formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
=iferror(index(A9:D13, match(F9, A9:A13, 0), match(G9, A9:D9, 0)))
```

Using your table:

[image]

Comment: Can ARRAYFORMULA be added to this formula?

Comment: Yes but in this case it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Untested formula from mobile phone-

```
=Index(B10:D13,Match(F9,A10:A13,0),Match(G9,B9:D9,0))
```

Comment: Can ARRAYFORMULA be added to this formula?

Comment: Yes can be added but I think you don't need array formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering *specifically* how to do this with VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP, per the post title, use this:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F9,A10:D13,HLOOKUP(G9,{A9:D9;SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A9:D9))},2,FALSE)))`

The outermost `IFERROR( )` is not necessary if you know for certain that your selected combination of choices will be found (or if you don't mind an error as a result if they are not found).

Comment: Can ARRAYFORMULA be added to this formula?

Comment: To do what exactly? You need to give more information. The short answer is "Yes, ARRAYFORMULA can be added to this formula." But I don't know what you're trying to do with it.